# Struts2 and polymorphic

Tags: struts2

I am having the followoing problem i have a main class Bussiness and two sub classes Company and Professional with different fileds added in each subclass.
How can I do it in Struts2?

Comment: what exactly you want to do in struts2? Your question is not clear enough

Comment: You need to revise your question to add a lot more detail. What are you trying to do? What error or problem are you encountering trying it? etc.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do seems to have nothing to do with struts 2... just create a package Model for example and put your classes inside